# How to get data by big data

Tags: magento2, database

i have data like this. How to get abc_accountnumber, please help me. It is near the bottom of data

```
    object(Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Address_Collection)#704 (33) {
  ["_itemsById":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    [165]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      object(Mage_Customer_Model_Address)#741 (17) {
        ["_customer":protected]=>
        object(Amasty_Customerattr_Model_Rewrite_Customer)#455 (24) {
          ["_customAttributes":protected]=>
          array(0) {
          }
          ["_fileAttributes":protected]=>
          array(0) {
          }
          ["_savedFileNames":protected]=>
          array(0) {
          }
          ["_eventPrefix":protected]=>
          string(8) "customer"
          ["_eventObject":protected]=>
          string(8) "customer"
          ["_errors":protected]=>
          array(0) {
          }
          ["_attributes":protected]=>
          NULL
          ["_addresses":protected]=>
          NULL
          ["_addressesCollection":protected]=>
          *RECURSION*
          ["_isDeleteable":protected]=>
          bool(true)
          ["_isReadonly":protected]=>
          bool(false)
          ["_cacheTag":protected]=>
          string(8) "customer"
          ["_resourceName":protected]=>
          string(17) "customer/customer"
          ["_resource":protected]=>
          NULL
          ["_resourceCollectionName":protected]=>
          string(28) "customer/customer_collection"
          ["_dataSaveAllowed":protected]=>
          bool(true)
          ["_isObjectNew":protected]=>
          NULL
          ["_data":protected]=>
          array(23) {
            ["entity_id"]=>
            string(2) "34"
            ["entity_type_id"]=>
            string(1) "1"
            ["attribute_set_id"]=>
            string(1) "0"
            ["website_id"]=>
            string(1) "1"
            ["email"]=>
            string(20) "name@abc.com"
            ["group_id"]=>
            string(2) "18"
            ["increment_id"]=>
            NULL
            ["store_id"]=>
            string(1) "1"
            ["created_at"]=>
            string(25) "2018-08-30T15:22:41+02:00"
            ["updated_at"]=>
            string(19) "2019-06-25 10:19:25"
            ["is_active"]=>
            string(1) "1"
            ["disable_auto_group_change"]=>
            string(1) "0"
            ["created_in"]=>
            string(5) "Admin"
            ["firstname"]=>
            string(9) "Christian"
            ["lastname"]=>
            string(5) "name"
            ["password_hash"]=>
            string(65) "f3e1b328be9109a0a1079952cf4ef71c:brhqesXt0Q09paLYXMs652KOqJNZfUo2"
            ["ws_user_id"]=>
            string(4) "4711"
            ["default_billing"]=>
            string(3) "165"
            ["default_shipping"]=>
            string(3) "165"
            ["password_created_at"]=>
            string(10) "1540266784"
            ["quickorderproducts"]=>
            string(1) "0"
            ["account_group"]=>
            string(153) "44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,6,5,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35"
            ["tax_class_id"]=>
            string(1) "3"
          }
          ["_hasDataChanges":protected]=>
          bool(true)
          ["_origData":protected]=>
          array(22) {
            ["entity_id"]=>
            string(2) "34"
            ["entity_type_id"]=>
            string(1) "1"
            ["attribute_set_id"]=>
            string(1) "0"
            ["website_id"]=>
            string(1) "1"
            ["email"]=>
            string(20) "name@abc.com"
            ["group_id"]=>
            string(2) "18"
            ["increment_id"]=>
            NULL
            ["store_id"]=>
            string(1) "1"
            ["created_at"]=>
            string(25) "2018-08-30T15:22:41+02:00"
            ["updated_at"]=>
            string(19) "2019-06-25 10:19:25"
            ["is_active"]=>
            string(1) "1"
            ["disable_auto_group_change"]=>
            string(1) "0"
            ["created_in"]=>
            string(5) "Admin"
            ["firstname"]=>
            string(9) "Christian"
            ["lastname"]=>
            string(5) "name"
            ["password_hash"]=>
            string(65) "f3e1b328be9109a0a1079952cf4ef71c:brhqesXt0Q09paLYXMs652KOqJNZfUo2"
            ["ws_user_id"]=>
            string(4) "4711"
            ["default_billing"]=>
            string(3) "165"
            ["default_shipping"]=>
            string(3) "165"
            ["password_created_at"]=>
            string(10) "1540266784"
            ["quickorderproducts"]=>
            string(1) "0"
            ["account_group"]=>
            string(153) "44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,6,5,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35"
          }
          ["_idFieldName":protected]=>
          string(9) "entity_id"
          ["_isDeleted":protected]=>
          bool(false)
          ["_oldFieldsMap":protected]=>
          array(0) {
          }
          ["_syncFieldsMap":protected]=>
          array(0) {
          }
        }
        ["_eventPrefix":protected]=>
        string(16) "customer_address"
        ["_eventObject":protected]=>
        string(16) "customer_address"
        ["_errors":protected]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["_resourceName":protected]=>
        string(16) "customer/address"
        ["_resource":protected]=>
        NULL
        ["_resourceCollectionName":protected]=>
        string(27) "customer/address_collection"
        ["_cacheTag":protected]=>
        bool(false)
        ["_dataSaveAllowed":protected]=>
        bool(true)
        ["_isObjectNew":protected]=>
        NULL
        ["_data":protected]=>
        array(30) {
          ["entity_id"]=>
          string(3) "165"
          ["entity_type_id"]=>
          string(1) "2"
          ["attribute_set_id"]=>
          string(1) "0"
          ["increment_id"]=>
          NULL
          ["parent_id"]=>
          string(2) "34"
          ["created_at"]=>
          string(19) "2018-08-25 11:22:41"
          ["updated_at"]=>
          string(19) "2019-06-25 10:19:25"
          ["is_active"]=>
          string(1) "1"
          ["firstname"]=>
          string(9) "Christian"
          ["lastname"]=>
          string(5) "name"
          ["company"]=>
          string(15) "abc abvc"
          ["city"]=>
          string(5) "LĂ¼bz"
          ["country_id"]=>
          string(2) "DE"
          ["region"]=>
          string(22) "region"
          ["postcode"]=>
          string(5) "19386"
          ["telephone"]=>
          string(9) "013254579"
          ["abc_email"]=>
          string(20) "name@abc.com"
          ["abc_accountnumber"]=>
          string(7) "8154711"
          ["prefix"]=>
          NULL
          ["middlename"]=>
          NULL
          ["suffix"]=>
          NULL
          ["fax"]=>
          NULL
          ["vat_id"]=>
          NULL
          ["wsc_zeile1"]=>
          NULL
          ["wsc_zeile2"]=>
          NULL
          ["wsc_zeile3"]=>
          NULL
          ["wsc_zeile4"]=>
          NULL
          ["street"]=>
          string(16) "Parchimer Str. 1"
          ["region_id"]=>
          string(2) "87"
          ["customer_id"]=>
          string(2) "34"
```

[image]

Comment: try with - getAbcAccountnumber()

Comment: Hi  Anas Mansuri, i tryed, but it not working, it NULL

Comment: try with getData();

Comment: i tryed it, it work, but haven't abc_accountnumber

Comment: Try this - $customer->getAddress()->getAbcAccountnumber();

Comment: it not work Vijay-CyberLocker, Call to undefined method getAddress()

Comment: Can you store getData in variable then used foreach and get value as getData or array index try this.

Comment: Try this     :     $your_printvariale[0]['abc_accountnumber'];   Like:    $data = $this->getData();  echo $data[0]['abc_accountnumber'];

Comment: i used foreach and this work, thanks all so much